# How to show whole y axis tick label in MUI Bar chart for horizontal layout?

Tags: bar-chart, mui-x-charts

For this example from MUI [bar chart](https://mui.com/x/react-charts/bars/#layout) I tried almost every prop unsuccessful to show whole tick label at y axis if it is longer than used in this example. Let say you change name of month to "December" or something longer, first two letters will be hidden.

MUI is using SVG  and  to show label, and with their attributes lengthAdjust and textLength I didn't succeed to show full label.
Also, I tried for tickLabelStyle every css property.
I expect to display whole label text for y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/11591) on the MUI-x project.

EDIT: Per the thread above, you can add `margin={{ left: 100 }}` to add more room.

Comment: I have used this: sx={{
          width: "80% !important",
          overflow: "visible !important"
        }} on BarChart component but your solution is probably better.